# Pi4 SD card formatting Scheme options

Tags: sd-card, pi-4, noobs

im formatting the SD card for NOOBS install, and I have few options to select the Scheme.

What would be the correct Scheme to select and why? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: MBR - because I think that's what the pi expects - though, if you're flashing an image onto it, it actually does not matter, since flashing flashes the boot record anyway

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't following the Foundation instructions? PS NOOBS is not used by most people